# Should we upvote questions without research effort?

Tags: discussion, voting, asking-questions

(There are many questions on the topic but my questions is not the same as the others. Scroll to the bottom to see more)

There are many questions over all the exchange sites that are very short and sweet, offering a generic (often "how does it work) prompt without showing any research effort. Do these questions warrant upvotes?

For example, [this graphics card question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/can-i-force-steam-to-use-my-nvidia-gpu-instead-of-the-integrated-intel-card?newreg=f32312e46d5842c497f38c540bb629b9) essentially asks for a tutorial on how to tell the computer to use a particular graphics card for a program. It shows no research effort, but rather sets up the prompt and says "how do I do this?". It has 22 upvotes, and I understand that this is due to the popularity of the content - I instictively clicked the upvote button myself when I went there with the same problem and got an answer. However, should this be the case? Should we be upvoting questions without research effort?

---

Duplicate review:
My question is not ["Why does this very localized question without showing research effort get so many upvotes?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171996/why-does-this-very-localized-question-without-showing-research-effort-get-so-man) because I understand *why* it happens - the popularity of the content. I'm asking if it is okay and accepted to upvote these questions as a responsible stack exchange user.

Comment: In chem.SE, the highest voted question shows a big lack of research. But usually when the community's consensus is to accept a question, one would need very good reasons to disagree. The two most important facts about this is: 1) As Deer Hunter has said below no one can force any kind of voting. 2) Many people like to blow with the wind. If I see a question with 3 upvotes it's very unlikely for me to downvote it.

Comment: @snickers10m "*I guess I'm asking for the community's consensus on it then... which I don't know if I can get just from asking a question on meta*" You'll get consensus from all comments and answers here, which won't be much. You're better off searching and reading - e.g.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better  - and - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor?lq=1 - etc reading *mainly* the answers, but some questions also give ideas/insight

Answer (score 3):

Nobody can force you to choose any particular voting procedure. The only guideline is "upvote if the question shows research effort, is **useful and clear**".

The question you cite may have helped many users (as in **useful**) and it was worded unambiguously (**clear**). Thus, the upvotes.

Even with this guideline, voting is subjective. StackExchange hopes that given enough page views, the law of large numbers somehow kicks in leading to the score reflecting the post's inner quality.

We know it ain't perfect (history-dependent voting - a spuriously `-2` question is less likely to attract upvotes). Yet it's somehow workable.

Comment: So, in general, if it can fit a couple of the "good question" criteria, it doesn't have to fit all of them to be a good question?

Comment: @snickers10m - goodness is subjective. You don't have to be a Ph.D. to ask a good question.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I'm asking for the community's consensus on it then... which I don't know if I can get just from asking a question on meta

Comment: Even if you have the opinion of all MSE users, you can't force people to vote strictly according to the rules, as explained already.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that's right, I'm simply searching for an answer because I, personally, would like to vote according to a consensus, and I'm sure there are others as well